# Using Pandas to represent 2D data series - what structure to use?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working with analysis of foot pressure, where each reading is a 52x44 matrix, and a full capture is a time series of these 2D readings.

This can easily be represented by a Numpy array of shape (52x44xN), with N depending on the sampling rate and duration of capture. With Numpy I already can perform all the operations I need (mostly slicing and simple descriptive statistics).

I am interested in exploring Pandas capabilities for that, but I wonder what would be suitable column names and structure.

With the Numpy 3D array, I have the indices I, J and N. If I use N as the index for a Pandas DataFrame, what would I use as data columns? I would find weird to use I, J and V (value) as columns, because that would create  explicit (and redundant) index values, actually using a (3 x (52*44*N)) shaped matrix.

Now if I put an array as the column value, the 3D slicing ("box" selection) would be problematic, wouldn't it?

(EDIT) I've seen something about MultiIndex, but I am not sure as how to use it.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I don't have any experience in it, but [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) is a popular and well supported python library for this type of thing.

Comment: Can you add an example of "Now if I put an array as the column value, the 3D slicing ("box" selection) would be problematic, wouldn't it?" What are you trying to accomplish, and why won't that work?

Also, perhaps you could consider `pandas.Panel` which is for 3-dimensional data. I've only used `DataFrame` before though, so no idea if that will solve your problem.

Comment: @user2570465 I've read the docs for Panel regarding this situation, and it looks like it would work. But I believe that, in fact, Pandas doesn't seem to add any benefit over Numpy _for this specific use case_, since the data is homogeneous (single data type), and the different columns would have no semantics besides plain indexing.

Comment: @user2570465 But in the end, yeah, I think either DataFrame/MultiIndex or "3D" Panel would be the structures to use in case someone _really_ wants to represent a 2D time series. I would be inclined to try the first one. What do you think about writing an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: @heltonbiker I posted an answer about the Pandas `Panel`. Glad to hear that it was a straightforward solution. I appreciate you accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using a Pandas `Panel` for 3-dimensional data.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html

For other people's reference, you can find information about 1D (`Series`), 2D (`Dataframe`), and 3D (`Panel`) Pandas structures here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html

Comment: It's worth noting that Pandas Panel has been deprecated since version 0.20, now officially in favor of using xarray for this kind of application.